# Setting markers colour in plotly 3D scatterplot according to R, G, B stored in DataFrame columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, plotly, scatter3d

I have the following pandas DataFrame:

```
>>> print(df.head())
         X         Y        Z   R   G   B
0 -846.160 -1983.148  243.229  22  24  19
1 -846.161 -1983.148  243.229  31  37  28
2 -846.157 -1983.148  243.231  20  21  18
3 -846.160 -1983.148  243.230  21  25  18
4 -846.159 -1983.147  243.233  38  48  34
```

And I plot data from it to 3D scatter plot like this:

```
import plotly.express as px
fig = px.scatter_3d(df, x='X', y='Y', z='Z')
fig.update_traces(marker=dict(size=4), selector=dict(mode='markers'))
fig.show()
```

The plot looks like below.

[image]

As you can see, every marker in the plot is blue. Is there any option, how to use my `R`, `G`, `B` columns from `df` DataFrame to change a colour of every marker in plot?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`graph_objs.Scatter3d`](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/blob/master/packages/python/plotly/plotly/graph_objs/scatter3d/__init__.py):

```py
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objs as go

df = pd.DataFrame({'X': [1,2,3,4,5,],
                   'Y': [1,3,2,4,1],
                   'Z': [4,1,3,4,1],
                   'R': [252, 11, 250, 21, 8],
                   'G': [1, 127, 251, 25, 244],
                   'B': [1, 28, 8, 128, 4]})

trace = go.Scatter3d(x=df.X,
                      y=df.Y,
                      z=df.Z,
                      mode='markers',
                      marker=dict(size=5,
                                  color=['rgb({},{},{})'.format(r,g,b) for r,g,b in zip(df.R.values, df.G.values, df.B.values)],
                                  opacity=0.9,))

data = [trace]

layout = go.Layout(margin=dict(l=0,
                               r=0,
                               b=0,
                               t=0))

fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
fig.show()
```

and you get:

[image]